# How to disable multiple callbacks in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have different callbacks for all my models. For a particular task I want to disable all callbacks not individually disable it.

```
 ActiveRecord::Base.descendants.each do |model|
   model.skip_callback(:create)
 end
```

Can I do something like this to disable all callbacks

Edit: I tried doing this and it worked

```
 ActiveRecord::Base.descendants.each do |model|
   model.reset_callbacks :save
   model.reset_callbacks :commit
   model.reset_callbacks :update
   model.reset_callbacks :validate
 end
```

Only problem is now how do I enable them back once the task is done